Unexpected ModuleNotFound errors setting up Azure Functions locally on Windows
this is my first time using Azure functions so I apologize if this is a noob question. My organization already set up everything for Azure in our repository, but now I'm attempting to run the functions locally on my Windows machine, which gives me a ton of ModuleNotFoundErrors. Here are the steps I'm taking to start the localhost:
> python -m venv .venv
> .venv\Scripts\activate
> pip install -r requirements.txt
> func start --python

I'm running my terminal as an administrator, and when I run pip install -r requirements.txt it says that all requirements are already satisfied. However, when I func start it returns a spew of ModuleNotFoundErrors, such as:
[2024-08-02T10:13:40.452Z] Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.durable_functions'. Cannot find module. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound. Current sys.path: ['C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64', 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\spayk\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Users\\spayk\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\spayk\\project']

This doesn't make sense to me since when I ran the pip install previously it returned Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions-durable==1.2.9 in c:\users\spayk\project\.venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.2.9). Additionally, when I look inside my .venv\Lib folder I can see the site packages installed there.
I've tried multiple ideas for fixing this issue, including even running an Ubuntu WSL so I can use tools like Homebrew and source commands. I think the problem might be with the paths leading towards the installs, but I'm not really sure how I could redirect those. For reference, everyone else in my organization develops on Mac, I'm the only Windows developer, so modifying the code base in a way that would mess up the Azure functionality on a MacOS environment isn't an option for me.
If anyone else has experienced something similar please let me know, and thanks in advance!

Follow the steps below to create and run the python durable function locally.

Either use the vs code template or cli command (func init) to create a function app which will have all the default file in it. You can also follow Create a Python Durable Functions app documentation.



Add given modules in requirements.txt file.

azure-functions 
azure-functions-durable


Execute below commands to install the modules.

python -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt



Added below code in function_app.py file.

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

myApp = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

# An HTTP-triggered function with a Durable Functions client binding
@myApp.route(route="orchestrators/{functionName}")
@myApp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def http_start(req: func.HttpRequest, client):
    function_name = req.route_params.get('functionName')
    instance_id = await client.start_new(function_name)
    response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return response

# Orchestrator
@myApp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def hello_orchestrator(context):
    result1 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "Seattle")
    result2 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "Tokyo")
    result3 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "London")

    return [result1, result2, result3]

# Activity
@myApp.activity_trigger(input_name="city")
def hello(city: str):
    return f"Hello {city}"


Execute the function as shown below. Please use latest version of Azure Function core Tools.

PS C:\Users\******\Documents\functionApp\78825191> .venv\scripts\activate
(.venv) PS C:\Users\******\Documents\functionApp\78825191> func host start                        
Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-05T08:02:37.495Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        http_start:  http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/{functionName}

        hello: activityTrigger

        hello_orchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-05T08:02:42.431Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000D2022A4'.
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.350Z] Executing 'Functions.http_start' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=0ca7f1e6-8e45-4730-b9da-6656677fa502)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.674Z] Executed 'Functions.http_start' (Succeeded, Id=0ca7f1e6-8e45-4730-b9da-6656677fa502, Duration=338ms)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.734Z] Executing 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=069d5ee9-d71b-4e78-af70-84a5335f760c)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.811Z] Executed 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=069d5ee9-d71b-4e78-af70-84a5335f760c, Duration=87ms)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.888Z] Executing 'Functions.hello' (Reason='(null)', Id=da9aefb1-2557-4344-88fa-ce740de24231)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.893Z] Executed 'Functions.hello' (Succeeded, Id=da9aefb1-2557-4344-88fa-ce740de24231, Duration=6ms) 
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.950Z] Executing 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=f0cabf9a-8d40-4ebf-ab5e-d125de8ec899)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.961Z] Executed 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=f0cabf9a-8d40-4ebf-ab5e-d125de8ec899, Duration=12ms)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.987Z] Executing 'Functions.hello' (Reason='(null)', Id=b0818bc2-df97-4d49-8dc8-413a048aa15d)
[2024-08-05T08:03:50.991Z] Executed 'Functions.hello' (Succeeded, Id=b0818bc2-df97-4d49-8dc8-413a048aa15d, Duration=3ms)
[2024-08-05T08:03:51.021Z] Executing 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=37a182eb-f45f-4613-9237-dd4b26170f29)
[2024-08-05T08:03:51.028Z] Executed 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=37a182eb-f45f-4613-9237-dd4b26170f29, Duration=8ms)
[2024-08-05T08:03:51.068Z] Executing 'Functions.hello' (Reason='(null)', Id=fd2e1c87-8687-4fea-a56a-eda0034e29d2)
[2024-08-05T08:03:51.074Z] Executed 'Functions.hello' (Succeeded, Id=fd2e1c87-8687-4fea-a56a-eda0034e29d2, Duration=6ms) 
[2024-08-05T08:03:51.120Z] Executing 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=deb08e4f-1245-434c-95c7-d3d0eabfc040)
[2024-08-05T08:03:51.139Z] Executed 'Functions.hello_orchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=deb08e4f-1245-434c-95c7-d3d0eabfc040, Duration=19ms)


